# Деструктуризация аргумента в функции

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Есть ли возможность деструктурировать поле из объекта в момент передачи в аргументах функции?
Пример:

```
const someFunc = obj.get(value, this.props.someProps)
```

Можно ли получить someProps прям в аргументах без полного обращения?

В моей ситуации get() - это библиотечная функция, не самописная.

Comment: Непонятен вопрос. Props - обычный объект, если вы получили его внутри компонента, то можете извлекать из него информацию по своему усмотрению

Comment: Я, наверное, тупой, но смысл фразы "прям в аргументах" от меня ускользает.

Comment: @Igor, я извиняюсь, вечер )) линтер ругается , говорит деструктуриуй someProps, а не пиши this.props.someProps

Comment: вот так можно `const { someProps } = this.props` и someProps будет переменная со значением this.props.someProps

Comment: да, но это я мог бы делать, если б я не присваивал результат библиотечной функции в переменную @ИльяЗеленько

Comment: Вам в любом случае нужно будет указать все три "части блока" для переменной. Будет это `this.props.someProps` или `const { someProps } = this.props;` или еще как-то. Смотрите по ситуации как лучше